# Complete list of packages in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Where can I find the full list of packages in python 3.x.

I have been searching on google - couple of web-site, but neither lists the full list.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: I doubt that such a list exists. Python packages are independent initiatives and don't think that there is a single "official" package registration service. Anyway, https://pypi.org/

Comment: Are you asking for the list of built-in packages available on your Python 3 installation? Or all the _locally_ installed packages? Or all the packages available to your app? Or all the public packages that you can install from pypi?

Comment: I am seeking all built-in packages. on continuing my google search, I found this - and looks like, this is what I was searching for.. sharing will all you, it could help.

https://pypi.org/search/?q=&o=

Answer (score 0):

While there will never be a list of every single library ever made for Python due to there being no single centralized distributing system, there's a couple of places you can always check:

Python standard library for the packages included with a Python install:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Python package index for at least most of the commonly used libraries:
https://pypi.org/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `sys.module` to view already imported modules. See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules).
2. If you want to see all available modules, not just the already imported ones, there is no such mechanism. But you could search for relevant folders and directories in the paths python will search to import modules, and guess which files/directories actually represent a python module (e.g. which files ends with `.py`, which dirs have a `__init__.py`… The list of search paths is in `sys.path`. So you could do

   import sys, os
   for python_search_path in sys.path:
   for item in os.listdir(python_search_path):
   module_file_candidate = os.path.join(python_search_path, item)
   # Test if module_file_candidate is a path to a module file/directory

   To do the check, you could use the help of the import module, `importlib`, and function like `importlib.util.find_spec`, `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader.is_package()` or `importlib.machinery.all_suffixes()`
3. If you install all you extraneous packages with pip, you can get them also with `pip list` in a shell or by using `subprocess.check_output(["python", "-m", "pip", "list"])`

```
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
algdeps            4.3.0
backoff            1.11.1
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.9
docopt             0.6.2
idna               3.3
importlib-metadata 4.8.2
keyring            23.4.0
pip                22.0.4
pyparsing          3.0.6
pywin32-ctypes     0.2.0
requests           2.26.0
setuptools         58.1.0
urllib3            1.26.7
zipp               3.6.0
```